# Bottomsheet Layout height issues

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have have a `ConstraintLayout` with `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`

The problem is, when I click on the edittext inside the bottomsheet and the keyboard appears, the bottomsheet changes his height. It happens on several cases, for example when I close keyboard, when I click a pin on the map.

Seems more like an android bug, is there a fix for that?

[image]

Comment: try changing the layout to linear layout if it's possible

Comment: @A.easazadeh  I have tried now, no difference

Comment: @ghita is this project on Github by any chance? I was looking for something like this for a while

Comment: hi rengineer, no it's for a client. but there are several examples on github

Comment: Oh okay thanks-I tried looking all over on Github but I cannot seem to find any. I 've been looking for a few days. Do you happen to know what I should be looking under?

Comment: https://github.com/michaelbel/BottomSheet

you can check with this library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating the `com.google.android.material:material` from `1.0.0` to `1.1.0-alpha07`  and adding to the bottomsheet behavior the following code:

`bottomSheetBehavior.saveFlags = BottomSheetBehavior.SAVE_ALL`

Hope it will save time for somebodyelse.